# ¿Por qué esta función BUSCARV devuelve todos los valores buscados aunque no estén en la matriz indicada?

Tags: excel, funciones

No estoy seguro de si el sitio es correcto para hacer esta pregunta, pero estoy trabajando con Excel.
Necesito saber qué elementos de la tabla A no se encuentran en la tabla B, visualmente, es obvio que hay elementos que no están. 
Sin embargo, al ejecutar la función BuscarV, esta devuelve todos los resultados como "Si está" aunque no estén. Y viceversa, devuelve elementos como "No está" cuando si se encuentran en el vector de búsqueda. Como por ejemplo, "Carpetas", que está en la tabla A y en la B, pero según la función "No está".
Ajunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta sería: ¿Qué es lo que está mal en esta fórmula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque la función `BUSCARV` necesita los parámetros valor buscado, la matriz donde se debe buscar, el indicador de columna y finalmente el parametro de comparacion, coloca 0 si el valor debe ser exactamente igual al de comparación y 1 si solo debe parecerse por decirlo de alguna forma, debes poner tu formula así:

```
BUSCARV(E2;$G$2:$H$25;2;0)
```

Answer (score 1):

En funcion `BUSCARV` deberias pasarle el ultimo parámetro lo cual te quedaria

Para que tu busqueda sea aproximada

```
BUSCARV(E2;$G$2:$H$25;2;VERDADERO)
```

Para que tu busqueda sea exacta

```
BUSCARV(E2;$G$2:$H$25;2;FALSO)
```